# Coova chilli: Could not generate configuration error

Tags: openwrt, coovachilli

Installed coova-chilli 1.3.1-svn on Ubiquiti Unifi AC-Lite AP running OpenWrt 18.06.2.
When trying to launch chilli with the command:

```
chilli --debug --fg
```

I am always getting the following error:

```
coova-chilli[27966]: options.c: 181: could not generate configuration (/var/run/chilli.27966.cfg.bin), sleeping one second
```

I have been stuck in this bug for so long. I tried doing changes in the configuration file, installing and reinstalling the coova-chilli package with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to run chilli for a first time as a service using `/etc/init.d/chilli start` command.

Below is a working chilli init.d service code. If you dont have service startup file, you will do a Copy and paste the below code inside "/etc/init.d/" as a file name "chilli". Then edit the paths for your configuration.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# chilli - CoovaChilli
#
# chkconfig: 2345 65 35
# description: CoovaChilli

# Source function library.
. /usr/local/etc/chilli/functions

exec="/usr/local/sbin/chilli"
prog=$(basename $exec)

[ -e /etc/sysconfig/$prog ] && . /etc/sysconfig/$prog

lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog

MULTI=$(ls /usr/local/etc/chilli/*/chilli.conf 2>/dev/null)
[ -z "$DHCPIF" ] && [ -n "$MULTI" ] && {
    for c in $MULTI; 
    do
        echo "Found configuration $c"
        DHCPIF=$(basename $(echo $c|sed 's#/chilli.conf##'))
        export DHCPIF
        echo "Running DHCPIF=$DHCPIF $0 $*"
        sh $0 $*
    done
    exit
}

pidfile=/usr/local/var/run/chilli.pid
CONFIG=/usr/local/etc/chilli.conf

if [ -n "$DHCPIF" ]; then
    CONFIG=/usr/local/etc/chilli/$DHCPIF/chilli.conf
    pidfile=/usr/local/var/run/chilli.$DHCPIF.pid
fi

[ -f $CONFIG ] || {
    echo "$CONFIG not found"
    exit 0
}

start() {
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "

    check_required

    /sbin/modprobe tun >/dev/null 2>&1
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

    [ -e /dev/net/tun ] || {
        (cd /dev; mkdir net; cd net; mknod tun c 10 200)
    }

    writeconfig
    radiusconfig

    test ${HS_ADMINTERVAL:-0} -gt 0 && {
        (crontab -l 2>&- | grep -v $0
        echo "*/$HS_ADMINTERVAL * * * * $0 radconfig") | crontab - 2>&-
    }

    test ${HS_LANIF_KEEPADDR:-0} -eq 0 && ip address add 0.0.0.0 dev $HS_LANIF

    daemon -- $exec -c $CONFIG
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    crontab -l 2>&- | grep -v $0 | crontab -

    killproc $prog
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $PIDFILE
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $RUN_D/$IPCFILE
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $CMDSOCK
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && /bin/rm -f /usr/local/var/run/chilli.*.cfg.bin
    return $retval
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}

case "$1" in
    start|stop|restart)
        $1
        ;;
    force-reload)
        restart
        ;;
    status)
        status $prog
        ;;
    try-restart|condrestart)
        if status $prog >/dev/null ; then
            restart
        fi
    ;;
    reload)
        # If config can be reloaded without restarting, implement it here,
        # remove the "exit", and add "reload" to the usage message below.
        # For example:
        # status $prog >/dev/null || exit 7
        # killproc $prog -HUP
        action $"Service ${0##*/} does not support the reload action: " /bin/false
        exit 3
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|try-restart|force-reload}"
        exit 2
esac
```

Make sure you installed daemon.If not it shows deamon not found.so install it.